# iOS using custom Arabic/Cyrillic fonts automatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, internationalization

I'm trying to learn if it is possible to use a custom Arabic and Cyrillic fonts without having to do a `switch/if-else` on the user's language setting.

I can successfully use my custom font in the app. I'd like to supply a custom Ar/Cy font the same way, and I know I could build it into the app. If I have my font `SpecialFont.otf` and also supply `SpecialFont-CY.otf` how would the OS know to use SpecialFontCY.otf when the user is using a Cyrillic language? Ideally the OS will know the user's primary font and would be able to select a font that matches/includes the correct glyphs for the language.

*PS. this is **not** a question on how to use a custom font, I can do that. I want to know how to supply multiple fonts for various languages to fully support the world without writing code like this:*

```
if NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first == "Arabic"
   let myFont = UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-AR", size: 17)
else if NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first == "Russian"
   let myFont = UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-CY", size: 17)
...etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using a UIFont, you want a UIFontDescriptor. With that you can set the font attribute `cascadeList`, which tells the system what order to select fonts based on glyph availability (i.e. look in SpecialFont, but if you can't find a glyph for ب, try SpecialFont-CY, and then SpecialFont-AR).

The point of a cascade list is to select the correct font for a given glyph. This way, if a string contains Cyrillic, Arabic, and Latin mixed together, it'll still work fine.

For example:

```
// Start with your base font
let font = UIFont(name:"SpecialFont", size: 17)!

// Create the ordered cascade list.
let cascadeList = [
    UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [.name: "SpecialFont-AR"]),
    UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [.name: "SpecialFont-CY"]),
]

// Create a new font descriptor based on your existing font, but adding the cascade list
let cascadedFontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.cascadeList: cascadeList])

// Make a new font base on this descriptor
let cascadedFont = UIFont(descriptor: cascadedFontDescriptor, size: font.pointSize)
```

This is covered in detail in [Creating Apps for a Global Audience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/201/) (WWDC 2018).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, but you can define a simple extension to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func preferred(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont{
        switch NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first {
        case "Arabic": return UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-AR", size: size)!
        case "Russian": return UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-CY", size: size)!
        default: return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size) // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is:

```
let myFont = UIFont.preferred(ofSize: 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check this somehow in order to determine what is the right language to set.

If you don't want to use `if/else` syntax, you can use ***Ternary Conditional Operator***.

```swift
let myFont = (NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first == "Arabic") ? UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-AR", size: 17) : UIFont(name:"SpecialFont-CY", size: 17)
```

Or more readable, like this:

```swift
let fontName = (NSLocale.preferredLanguages.first == "Arabic") ? "SpecialFont-AR" : "SpecialFont-CY"
let myFont = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 17)
```